# What to do with unfocused question that was edited?

Tags: discussion, unclear

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32631627/linux-convert-masm-lst-file-to-bat-file-for-execution-on-windows) shows that the OP is confusing concepts. I was about to edit the question to make it relevant, but feel that it will be too broad anyways.
Not to mention that answers were given explaining that the question did not make sense.

My inclination is to edit the question and either

1. Delete the old answers
2. Just leave them be

Or just delete the question and have the OP ask a new one?

Any suggestions how to handle this?

Comment: Answers should not be used to indicate that the question does not make sense, comments should. It will be difficult to make the question useful for anyone else, I think.

Comment: Regarding the level of OP background knowledge, it's very similar to one I saw recently where was asked "how to open a PDF with Notepad it works with other files I NEED S.O. TO TELL ME HOW,,," [paraphrased from memory]. Left a comment for the OP, voted to close as "Unclear what you are asking".